# MATLAB Box Plot for large groups of Measurements

Tags: matlab, boxplot

I've got basically three large groups of measurements and im trying to generate a BoxPlot with 4 Boxes. One box for each group and the last one for all groups joined.

I've tried with this code

```
A = rand(1417725,1)
B = rand(2236508,1)
C = rand(3100641,1)
D = [A;B;C]

X= [A;B;C;D]

group = [repmat({'a'},1417725,1); repmat({'b'},2236508,1); repmat({'c'},3100641,1); repmat({'d'},6754874,1)];

boxplot(X,group)
```

but at the end i get " Out of memory" and i can't get the plot.

do you have any idea to solve this problem??

Thank you!

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but how about subsampling your data with randsample first?  With a dataset that large you can probably still visualize it fine using say, 10% of the data.

Comment: That's a really good idea... I think that to visualize it's more than enough.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a huge (in terms of memory) cell array of strings, create a much smaller array of for instance int8 integers:

```
group = [ones(size(A),'int8');2*ones(size(B),'int8');3*ones(size(C),'int8');4*ones(size(D),'int8')];
```

Then, after plotting, change the labels in the plot to the desired names:

```
set(gca, 'XTick', 1:4, 'XTickLabel', {'a','b','c','d'});
```

Maybe you have enough memory to do it this way..

Comment: Clear all variables (including `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`) but `X` and `group` before plotting. If this is still not working, try using single precision variables.

Comment: is still not working... do you know if there is an other way to plot each group separate and somehow "hold on" the plot an set the new box in an other 'Tick'??